# Faster implementation of more than one input in a single line (Java)

Tags: java, input

Well, this might be a silly problem.

I just want a faster implementation of following problem

I want to take three integer input in a single line eg:

```
10 34 54
```

One way is to make a BufferedReader and then use readLine()
which will read the whole line as a string 
then we can use StringTokenizer to separate three integer. (Slow implemetation)

Another way is to use 'Scanner' and take input by nextInt() method. (Slower than previous method)

I want a fast implementation to take such type of inputs since I have to read more than 2,000,000 lines and these implementations are very slow.

My implementation:

```
BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

for(i=0;i<n;i++) {
    str=br.readLine();
    st = new StringTokenizer(str);
    t1=Integer.parseInt(st.nextElement().toString());
    t2=Integer.parseInt(st.nextElement().toString());
    z=Long.parseLong(st.nextElement().toString());
}
```

This one is looped for n times. ( n is number of entries)
Since I know each line will contain only three integer there is no need to check for `hasMoreElements()`

Comment: How slow? Can you post some example code that you used, as well as timings?

Comment: You could use BufferedReader and do your own parsing, specialized to collecting N chars until you see a blank, or the end of the string. This might be faster. Note you will achieve better performance in all cases by using BufferedReader with a bigger buffer (10kB will already help a lot).

Comment: @SteveMcLeod I used this method on a Programming Website and got Time Limit Exceeded. So I thought there would be a better method to do it.

Comment: It will always be less-than-optimal to read > 200k text lines and parse three ints out of them. Better do that only once, then store a binary (stream?) version of the data, and use that one next time.

Comment: @TheBlastOne Can you provide an example implementation?
I think you got the question wrong. Every line contains three integers.

Comment: `StringTokenizer` is deprecated - the [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/StringTokenizer.html) recommends you use `String.split()` instead.

Comment: @assylias Tried that version too! But eclipse wasn't giving any warning with StringTokenizer.(Using JAVA 1.6 update 24)

Comment: @Android >>Every line contains three integers<< that´s why I suggested to loop over each line, scan for blanks (or line end), and collect the digits, making ints out of them upon blank/line end. That´s what I called a "specialized scanner". Where´s my error?

Comment: @Android post what you´ve tried, and we´ll post our suggestions in code. This it not a "shoh mee teh codez" forum, sorry.

Comment: @TheBlastOne Am sorry. My fault. Well can you provide an implementation of specialized scanner? That was my question.

Comment: @TheBlastOne Done. I never said that this is "shoh mee teh codez" forum. I just described my implementation. Some people understood but some like you wanted a code. And I have posted it. Now don't ask that why you haven't initialized the String str.

Comment: Where is the loop? If you loop this code 200000 times, you get 200000 readers reading the first line once. Show us your actual code. Please. Optimizing a loop is impossible if the loop is not there.

Comment: @TheBlastOne Use some common sense. No one is going to put the BufferedReader line in a loop

Comment: @AndroidDecoded do you create a new `StringTokenizer` (`st = new StringTokenizer(str);`) in your loop?

Comment: Yeah. Defined StringTokenizer st; outside the loop.

Comment: Performance tests I've done in the past on such loops show that it is not necessary (and sometimes unhelpful) to create a variable outside the loop and reuse it. The Java JIT compiler is really good at optimising variables repeatedly created inside a loop.

Comment: You really need to do some profiling I think, to find the slow part of your code. Then you can look into how to speed it up. At the moment we can only guess if readLine(), the creation of StringTokenizer, nextElement(), or parseInt() is the slowest part.

Comment: I took a look at the source code for StringTokenizer. Constructing a new instance is expensive...lots of code is executed for each one you create.

Comment: @Android -- OK look at my answer, and rip it apart, please :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I just want a faster implementation of following problem.

The chances are that you DON'T NEED a faster implementation.  Seriously.  Not even with a 2 million line input file.

The chances are that:

- more time is spent processing the file than reading it, and
- most of the "read time" is spent doing things at the operating system level, or simply waiting for the next disk block to be read.

My advice is to not bother optimizing this **unless** the application as a whole takes too long to run.  And when you find that this is the case, profile the application, and use the profile stats to tell you where it could be worthwhile spending effort on optimization.

(My gut feeling is that there is not much to be gained by optimizing this part of your application.  But don't rely on that.  Profile it!)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a basic example that will be pretty fast:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("myfile.txt"));
    String line;
    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        for (String s : line.split(" ")) {
            final int i = Integer.parseInt(s);
            // do something with i...
        }
    }
    reader.close();
}
```

However your task is fundamentally going to take time.

If you are doing this on a website and reaching a timeout, you should consider doing it in a background thread, and send a response to the user saying that the data is being processed. You'll probably need to add a way for the user to check on the progress.

Comment: Will try this one. But I think it will offer the similar time as StringTokenizer. By Programming Website I meant Programming Competition ( Similar to TopCoder).

Comment: @Android lol...come on, post your code, and your timing results, and we´ll see what we can do for you. Everything else is a shot in the dark for us and a waste of time.

Comment: Also, Integer.parseInt will be hard to replace with something more efficient AND readable. This might be a case of "string-to-number-conversion-is-not-trivial-and-takes-quite-some-time" underestimation. I.e. it might be the string split (or scanner use) is not the biggest performance gap here.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I mean when I say "specialized scanner". Depending upon parser's (or split's) efficiency, this might be a bit faster (it probably is not):

```
BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(...);  
for(i=0;i<n;i++) 
{     
    String str=br.readLine();
    long[] resultLongs = {-1,-1,-1};
    int startPos=0;
    int nextLongIndex=0;
    for (int p=0;p<str.length();p++)
    {
        if (str.charAt(p)== ' ')
        {
            String intAsStr=str.substring(startPos, p-1);
            resultLongs[nextLongIndex++]=Integer.parseInt(intAsStr);
            startpos=p+1;
        }
    }
    // t1, t2 and z are in resultLongs[0] through resultLongs[2]     
    }
```

Hths.

And of course this fails miserably if the input file contains garbage, i.e. anything else but longs separated by blanks.

And in addition, to minimize the "roundtrips" to the OS, it is a good idea to supply the buffered reader with a nonstandard (bigger-than-standard) buffer.

The other hint I gave in the comment refined: If you have to read such a huge text file more than once, i.e. more than once after it has been updated, you could read all longs into a data structure (maybe a List of elements that hold three longs), and stream that into a "cache" file. Next time, compare the text file's timestamp to the "cache" file's. If it is older, read the cache file. Since stream I/O does not serialize longs into its string representation, you will see much, much better reading times.

EDIT: Missed the startPos reassignment.
EDIT2: Added the cache idea explanation.